# Gerrit code/peer review data extraction

Tags: gerrit

I want to extract data of code review repository for projects using Gerrit or Rietveld review system like Android, Google chromium, Firefox, Eclipse. Are there any APIs to perform extraction?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Gerrit the server is running, you want to use the REST API - http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/rest-api.html

Comment: Can you please help with Rietveld. Project like Google chromium uses Rietveld tool for code review. How can we extract data from chromium code review repository?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any public API for Rietveld.

Comment: No probs Brad. Thanks a lot for your help.